# Where my database query is wrong?

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I have a database query

```
       $extras = DB::select(

        'SELECT p.*
        FROM products p 
        WHERE required_product IS NULL 
        UNION ALL
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p, orders o 
WHERE p.required_product = o.product_id 
AND o.user_id =' .  $user->id .  'UNION ALL
SELECT p.* , "onlyOnce" product_type
FROM products p, orders o, only_once on 
WHERE p.required_product = o.product_id
AND p.id = on.product_id 
AND p.id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM orders WHERE o.product_id = p.id and o.user_id ='.$user->id.')'
);
```

Here is my tables structure:

Product table: http://prntscr.com/k6jdv7

Orders table: `product_id,user_id`

Users table: `id,name,last_server,timestamps`

Comment: What's the error returned?

Comment: You can't union tables with different number of columns or with columns that have different types. You have  `p.* , "onlyOnce" product_type` on the last select but only `p.*` on the first two

Comment: .. Hm im not sure i understand what to make. Can you give code or example

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Syntax error.

Try this...

```
$extras = DB::select(

    'SELECT p.*
    FROM products p 
    WHERE required_product IS NULL 
    UNION ALL
SELECT p.* 
FROM products p, orders o 
WHERE p.required_product = o.product_id 
AND o.user_id =' .  $user->id .  ' UNION ALL
SELECT p.* , "onlyOnce" product_type
FROM products p, orders o, only_once 
WHERE p.required_product = o.product_id
AND p.id = on.product_id 
AND p.id NOT IN (SELECT product_id FROM orders WHERE o.product_id = p.id and o.user_id ='.$user->id.')'
);
```